# upgrading statsmodels to a higher version

Tags: python, pip, statsmodels

I am trying to upgrade statsmodels to the version v.0.12 but I cant. The `pip install` gives me the version 0.11. How can install this specific version of statsmodels.

Comment: What is your OS/python version?

Comment: [`statsmodels` 0.11](https://pypi.org/project/statsmodels/0.11.0/) supports Python 3.5+, [`statsmodels` 0.12](https://pypi.org/project/statsmodels/0.12.0/) supports Python 3.6+. I guess you use Python 3.5 so you cannot install `statsmodels` 0.12.

Comment: @FlyingTeller I have python 3.8 and my OS is catalina 10.15.7

Comment: @phd it is possible however `python --version` and  `python` return python 3.8

Comment: Have you tried to use `python -m pip install` to make sure that the 3.8 python verion is sued?

Comment: @FlyingTeller thank you for your reply. Could you just confirm what should i put after ìnstall` in your command. Just to confirm I have tried that command with statsmodels and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found it on their website (`statsmodels.org`). Here what I typed:

```
 pip install -U statsmodels
```

Now, I am running the 012 version.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [link](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/install.html), it has min dependency to install statsmodel 0.12.0 version upgrade.

Mentioning minimum dependency here -

- Python >= 3.8
- NumPy >= 1.18
- SciPy >= 1.4
- Pandas >= 1.0
- Patsy >= 0.5.2

You need to upgrade python first and then upgrade statsmodel package